# Node js: getting an error Cannot GET /route when i use get method

Tags: node.js, express

When I use the "use" method my code works fine, but when I use the "get"  it gives an error: "Cannot GET /route1".

My Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');

const routes = require('./routes/handlers');

app.use(express.static('public'));

const hbs = expbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/mainLayout'),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/pieces'),
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/route1', routes);

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server is starting at port ', 8080);
});
```

I am new to node js, please tell me can i define routes with "get" method.

Comment: What is inside your /routes/handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your routes/handlers.js look something like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function greetUser(req, res){
    res.send("Welcome dear user");
}
router.get("/", greetUser);
router.post("/", (req, res)=>{ res.send("user registered") });

module.exports = router
```

The problem here is this last line, this router object which is being exported works fine for app.use middleware, while `.get or .post expects 2nd parameter to be a function`

If you export this `greetUser` function from your router as well or receive this function from anywhere, this should start functioning well. Practically it would be

```
app.get("/route1", (req, res)=>{ res.send({status : true, message : "sample JSON"})})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using router you coudn't use get method.

Here is the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router).

Only the handler has access to get method. `app.use` will add path to api route which point to get,post and etc.

You could only explicitly define a get as a standalone get route.

```
app.get('/route1', (req, res) => {
   res.send("You have hit route1 - get");
});
```

**When using router you could only include the router object as a parameter in `app.use(path, routerObj)` method**.

Answer (score 0):

app.get('/route1', routes);

woulde be app.use('/route1', routes);